# How to delete empty lines on visual studio code with the vim mode

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to delete many empty lines from a huge file. On other editors with `vim`, or `vim` itself, I could just do:

```
:%s/\n\n/\n/g
```

But neither if I use `\r` or `\t` it doesn't work. Seems like some `vim` features are missing on the editor. Is there any configuration to make that work or another way to do that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure VS Code doesn't support vim features like this... If you really need those features you'll have to stick with vim.

Comment: I would use an external script for that. `sed`, Perl, Python, whatever you have installed - it's a one-liner in each.

Comment: Search and replace "^\n" with regex option selected and replace with nothing works for me.

Comment: In some case you may need to use "^\r\n" as the search term.

Comment: @Mark comment is works perfectly for this case.

Comment: If this was Vi/Vim, I would use `:g/^$/d` instead of a substitution. Typically Vim emulators have poor ex command support. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have advanced Vim functionality work within VScode, you can leverage its Neovim integration.

First, you'll have to install Neovim. For instructions, check out: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim

Then, adjust the following settings in your user configuration:

```
// Use neovim on backend. (only works for Ex commands right now). You should restart VScode after enable/disabling this for the changes to take effect. NOTE: Neovim must be installed (v0.2.0) and neovimPath must be set the executable in order for this setting to work. Otherwise, vscodevim will crash.
  "vim.enableNeovim": true,

// Path to run neovim executable. For example, /usr/bin/nvim, or  C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\nvim.exe
  "vim.neovimPath": "nvim",
```

Restart VScode. Now you can use Vim Ex commands, since the commands are sent to a headless Neovim instance that's running in the background. You can even use installed Vim plugin functions to a certain degree.

Comment: Yay! Thanks ! Neovim did it! Everything works like on vim now.

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: @mattf What command works for you? I've enabled `neovim` but the command `:%s/\n\n/\n/g` still doesn't remove empty lines. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @UnderBlue592 the command `:%s/\n\n/\n/g` isn't for removing empty lines but double empty lines, that is, two line breaks in sequence that can't have tabs, spaces or anything else on them. Maybe what you want is `:%s/\n//g` ? That will remove empty line breaks. After I enabled neovim all those work like they do in vim/nvim.